# SSRS: add a line chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I created this chart here: 
[image]

I add a new series in my chart with a value of 75 (green line).

I would like to show the green line in steps. I tried it with this expression here:

```
=iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-08-09 00:00:00",75,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-09-13 00:00:00",77,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-10-11 00:00:00",79,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-11-08 00:00:00",81,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-12-13 00:00:00",83,0 ) ) ) ))
```

but this shows me an error

> Too many arguments to 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean,
>   TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'

@AKM : I edited my expression now my chart looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because there's too many arguments, as said in the error.

The iif work like that :

> **IIF(** CND **,** DWT **,** DWF **)**

- CND = Condition, in your case : Fields!Datum.Value = "..."
- DWT = Display When True, in your case : 75, 77 ...
- DWF = Display When False, it's like the else statement, in your case : 0

Now look at your iif :

```
=iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-08-09 00:00:00",75,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-09-13 00:00:00",77,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-10-11 00:00:00",79,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-11-08 00:00:00",81,0, iif(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-12-13 00:00:00",83,0 ) ) ) ))
```

The construction of your iif is taking 4 arguments, which is incorrect :

> **IIF(** CND **,** DWT **,** DWF *, IIF(...)* **)**

You must replace your DWF by your next IIF so it looks like

> **IIF(** CND **,** DWT **,** *IIF(...)* **)**

What you are looking for must be :

```
=IIF(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-08-09 00:00:00", 75, IIF(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-09-13 00:00:00", 77, IIF(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-10-11 00:00:00", 79, IIF(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-11-08 00:00:00", 81, IIF(Fields!Datum.Value = "2015-12-13 00:00:00", 83, 0)))))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it shows me no error but my graph is not looking as I wish.

Comment: How is your Field Datum being populated? I think your problem might come from the fact that you try to compare a Date/Time field to a string, so it never go in the true part of your IIF

Comment: I used weeknumber `="W" & DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!Datum.Value)`

Comment: in your IIF, try to replace all your "Fields!Datum.Value" to "CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd"))"

Comment: `=IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value),"2015-08-09 00:00:00")), 75, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value),"2015-09-13 00:00:00")), 77, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value),"2015-10-11 00:00:00")), 79, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value),"2015-11-08 00:00:00")), 81, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value),"2015-12-13 00:00:00")), 83, 0)))))` like this here

Comment: Something more like this :
=IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")) + " 00:00:00" = "2015-08-09 00:00:00", 75, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")) + " 00:00:00" = "2015-09-13 00:00:00", 77, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")) + " 00:00:00" = "2015-10-11 00:00:00", 79, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")) + " 00:00:00" = "2015-11-08 00:00:00", 81, IIF(CStr(Format(CDate(Fields!Datum.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd")) + " 00:00:00" = "2015-12-13 00:00:00", 83, 0)))))

Comment: And the result is a flat line equal to 0?

Comment: This is normal according to your iif, he check the dates, and display the value when he find them. The 2015-08-09, it displays 75 (first peak), the 2015-09-13, it displays 77 (second peak), etc ... But for all the other dates, it displays 0. If you want it to be more smoothed, maybe try to change your "0" at the end of your IIF to "Nothing". (Sorry for my english)

Comment: yes I understand it, but I would like to show it like a line not like a flat line, is this possible to add these values in a line chart

Comment: I think if you replace the 0 by Nothing, it will not put the line back to 0 every time he don't find a value, but he will link the values he got. If you want it to be more like a curve, change the series type to a Smoothed Line

Comment: I see my explanation on the IIF expression is already being copied. Quite funny. +1 for solving his problem tho.